# efetuar select somente pelo mês de uma determinada coluna - mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

Bom quero fazer o select com a condição que a tal coluna tenha determinado mês, e somente traz resultados deste mês.

tava fazendo assim, mas não deu certo.

```
SELECT * from funcionarios where dataEntrada = month(10);
```

estou usando mysql workbeanch

Answer (score 12):

Para conseguir filtrar determinados registros dentro do MySQL, você pode fazer da seguinte forma:

**Filtrando registros pelo Dia**

```
SELECT * FROM tabela WHERE DAY(data) = 'dia_escolhido'
```

**Filtrando registros pelo Mês**

```
SELECT * FROM tabela WHERE MONTH(data) = 'mes_escolhido'
```

**Filtrando registros pelo Ano**

```
SELECT * FROM tabela WHERE YEAR(data) = 'ano_escolhido'
```

Usando Day, Month, Year - consegue filtrar corretamente os dados.

Comment: Existem alguns casos de hora minutos e segundos ? @André Baill