# Pegando itens mensal ELOQUENT MODEL

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel-eloquent

Bom estou precisando fazer um `query` onde eu tenho que trazer todos os itens listados do mês em que estamos.

Na `query` que ja fiz estou trazendo todas com `status` `O` de `OK`:

```
$vendas = Encomenda::where('FlgStEncomenda', 'O')->count();
```

Na minha estrutura de tabela tenho um `created_at` que é a data de criação, composta por `data` e `hora` da seguinte forma `2016-11-02 16:25:03` através dela que preciso fazer a pesquisa. Assim tenho que retornar todas as `vendas` registradas este mês.

Comment: Você está usando o Laravel 5.3?

Comment: nao, estou utilizando o 5.2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Na versão [laravel](/questions/tagged/laravel) até ***5.2*** utilize o [`whereRaw`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/queries#advanced-where-clauses):

```
$mes = date('m');

$vendas = Encomenda::where('FlgStEncomenda', 'O')
                   ->whereRaw("MONTH(created_at)={$mes}") 
                   ->count();
```

***ou***

```
$vendas = Encomenda::where('FlgStEncomenda', 'O')
                   ->whereRaw("MONTH(created_at)=?", array($mes)) 
                   ->count();
```

---

Na versão [laravel](/questions/tagged/laravel) **5.3** utilize o novo método [`whereMonth`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/queries#conditional-clauses):

```
$mes = date('m');

$vendas = Encomenda::where('FlgStEncomenda', 'O')
                   ->whereMonth("created_at",$mes) 
                   ->count();
```

<sub>**Observações:** no `whereRaw` poder ser utilizado qualquer função existente no banco, como por exemplo nesse [link do SOPT](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/86654/54880), possui a `SQL` referente dia, mês e ano filtros obtidos de um campo `date` ou `datetime` em Banco [mysql](/questions/tagged/mysql). Também devo salientar que o `whereRaw` funciona nas versões atuais do [laravel](/questions/tagged/laravel).</sub>

***Referencias***:

- [Where Clauses - Laravel 5.3](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/queries#where-clauses)
- [Where Exists Clauses](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/queries#where-clauses)

Comment: Você é simplesmente o melhor kkk vlw

Comment: Obrigado, mas, sou mero mortal somente querendo ajudar a disseminar tecnologia...!

Comment: So para tirar uma duvida, caso eu queira ano, e dia existem também funções auxiliares ? Caso não for pedir muito e de forma a incrementar a resposta com conteúdo extra, que não fuja dos padrões do Stackoverflow. Seria de grande valia para comunidade.

Comment: @RenanRodrigues eu fiz uma edição e coloquei um link que faz a referencia dos filtros de uma data como foi dito por ti no seu comentário. É o mesmo processo, agora é só colocar a SQL de acordo com o que você precisa, era isso?

Comment: Só lembrando que cada banco possui as suas funções particulares e com `whereRaw` é possivel programar para os bancos que já possuem implementação no Laravel.