# Agrupar itens por mês e contá-los laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.2

Preciso agrupar e contar todos os itens por `mês`. Utilizo `Laravel 5.2`, tentei fazer assim:

```
$mes = date('m');
$vendas = Encomenda::where('FlgStEncomenda', 'O')
         ->group("MONTH(created_at)={$mes}")
         ->count();
```

Preciso que retorne assim:

```
[0] 5
[1] 10
[2] 4
[3] 11
[4] 107
[5] 110
[6] 120
[7] 5
[8] 103
[9] 104
[10] 102
[11] 0
```

Onde o `índice` significa o `mês`, e no caso do mês que ainda não chegou retornar 0. Tem como fazer isto com `Eloquente`?

Comment: Pra retornar 0 você vai ter que fazer um `array` manualmente de 1 a 12 ou criar uma tabela de meses na sua base e fazer um `Right Join`.

Comment: Seria legal criar a tabela, ficaria mais limpo o código.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$mes = date('m');
$vendas = Encomenda::where('FlgStEncomenda', 'O')
         ->groupBy(\DB::raw('MONTH(created_at)'))
         ->select(\DB::raw('MONTH(created_at) as Mes, count(*) as Quantidade'))   
         ->pluck('Mes','Quantidade');


$grafico = [1 => 0, 
            2 => 0, 
            3 => 0, 
            4 => 0, 
            5 => 0, 
            6 => 0, 
            7 => 0, 
            8 => 0, 
            9 => 0, 
            10 => 0, 
            11 => 0, 
            12 => 0];

foreach($vendas as $key => $value)
{
     $grafico[(int)$key] = (int)$value;
}
```

Se quiser pesquisar por ano:

```
$ano = date('Y');
$vendas = Encomenda::where('FlgStEncomenda', 'O')
         ->whereRaw("YEAR(created_at)={$ano}")
         ->groupBy(\DB::raw('MONTH(created_at)'))
         ->select(\DB::raw('MONTH(created_at) as Mes, count(*) as Quantidade'))   
         ->pluck('Mes','Quantidade');
```

<sub>Já até tinha feito [uma resposta com whereRaw](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/164954/54880).</sub>

Comment: Gostei desse jeito. Sempre fazia diferente. Você coloca um valor `default` e só instancia quando tiver.

Answer (score 2):

Pra retornar 0 tem que um `array` para fazer a combinação de meses. Senão pode-se criar uma tabela para meses e fazer um Join.

```
$vendas = Encomenda::select(DB::raw('MONTH(created_at) AS mes, count(id) AS qtd'))
          ->groupBy(DB::raw("MONTH(created_at)"))
          ->orderBy('mes')
          ->where('FlgStEncomenda', 'O')
          ->lists('mes', 'qtd')
          ->toArray();

$arrMeses = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12];

foreach($arrMeses as $key => $mes){
    if($mes == $vendas[$key]){
        $arrFoo[$mes] = $vendas[$key];
    }
    else{
        $arrFoo[$mes] = 0;
    }
}

dd($arrFoo);
```

Comment: Brother so a titulo para vc alterar, tem uma variavel $value dentro do primeiro if, que não está instanciada em local nenhum

Comment: Bem observado. Eu alterei no `foreach` e esqueci de alterar dentro.